# What is the outbound port for a telnet request from A to B

Tags: port, telnet

When from machine A, you do a telnet to machine B, you specify ip and port of B.
But what is the port on A from which the request originates? Does it pick any random port that is free?

Comment: The actual way is probably OS-dependent, but you can think of it as random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet runs on top of TCP. TCP clients use *ephemeral ports*. Most OSes allocate a special range of ports for this use, and when a new connection is to be opened, they select an arbitrary available port. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port for more information.